# c# application checkbox to connect to different databases

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

In my windows forms application I have a scenario like this:

I have 5 checkboxes which awaits user input. When the user clicks a checkbox,my application should connect to a database. Clicking each checkbox should connect to different different databases. For simplicity I have given my ip addresses and all details in app config as

```
<add key="SQLServer1" value="mmm.mm.mm.m,abcd" />
<add key="SQLServer2" value="nnn.nn.nn.n,wxyz" />
```

I have written the code like this:

```
ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + ***** + ";Initial Catalog=" + Master + ";Persist Security Info=True;Connect Timeout=0;User ID=" + ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["username"] + ";Password=" + ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["password"];
```

I should get help from you people where I marked *. What I meant by * is that my application should be able to connect with relevant ip based on what the user clicked..

Is there any chance for what I said?

Any other alternatives are also really appreciated..

Comment: You can declare a variable and use if statement, then based on your checkbox change the variable(read from config and assign to variable)...

Comment: @Sam:But as I said, if I have 5 checkboxes, then I should have 5 if conditions..right?

Comment: Yes that is right or use switch statement

Comment: yes. you must have conditions to do that

Comment: I'm not sure this is of great help to you, but I'm guessing you could simply use the `Tag` property of the checkboxes. Write the key "SQLServer?" in that `Tag` property, in the Visual designer and in whatever `CheckBox` event handler you had in mind just do something like: `ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ (sender as Control).Tag.ToString() ] + ";Initial Catalog=" + Master + .....`

Answer (score 1):

How are you connecting to the database?
Via `Entity Framework`, or `dbcontext`, or custom `SQLConnection` classes?

One thing you can do , as soon as user selects a checkbox, get the value of connection string and server Ip from `web.config`  as

```
ConnectionStringSettings conSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[VARIABLENAME];
```

and the app setting.

Replace the **** by app setting value and pass the connectionstring to the database connection class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use formatted variables like shown below:

```
string connectionString = String.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog=" + Master + ";Persist Security Info=True;Connect Timeout=0;User ID=" + ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["username"] + ";Password=" + ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["password"], <get value from checkbox>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Each checkBox has a checkBox.Checked parameter, so you can make a function that will insert the proper IP address when a checkBox is checked:

`if(checkBox1.Checked)
{
string DataSource = some IP address;
}`

and you repeat this code for each pair of checkBox/IP address you have.

P.S since you probably want to connect to only one database in one moment, you should use radioButtons instead of checkBoxes

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why you use `CheckBox`. if you need yo be connected to only one DB you should use `RadioBox`. if anyway you need several DB you can registed the checkBox Checked event:

```
     this.checkBox1.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.checkBox1_CheckedChanged);
```

and do:

```
  private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     if (checkBox1.Checked)
     {
        string currStr = ConnectionString.Replace("*****", currIP);// the currIP is up to u  
     }
     else
     {

     }

  }
```

now you can put them all in a list

```
List<string> connStrings = new List<string>();
```

and do

```
  private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     string currStr = ConnectionString.Replace("*****", currIP);// the currIP is up to u  

     if (checkBox1.Checked)
     {
        connStrings.Add(currStr);
     }
     else
     {
        connStrings.Remove(currStr);
     }

  }
```

now that you got them all in a list you can use it with a `foreach`

```
foreach(string curr in connStrings)
{
}
```

i do remind that you'll have to **register each `CheckBox` to his own event method**

Answer (score 0):

I had a scenario where i had to use 5 different databases in one application.

What is did is, i had a single class **DBUtility** which provides all database related functionality. in this class i had a method called init() which initializes my connection string.

so i created other 4 classes which inherited from the main class DBUtility and override the init() method to different connection strings.

You can also create similar structure and then based on checkbox selection create object of required class

e.g.

```
DBUtility obj = new DBUtility2();
```

where

```
public class DBUtility
{
public SqlConnection cn;
 public void init()
{
//initialize cn here
}

public DataSet getdata(string query)
{
//execute query using cn
}
}

public class DBUtility2 : DBUtility
{
public void init()
{
//initialize cn here
}
}
```